# How can I use auth on vue component ? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: authentication, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My view blade like this :

```
@if (Auth::user())
    <favorite :id="{{ $store->id }}"></favorite>
@else
    <a href="{{url('/login?red='.Request::path())}}" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>Favorite
    </a>
@endif
```

`Auth::user()` works

But, when I try on vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
    <div v-if="Auth::user()">
        <favorite :id="item.id"></favorite>
    </div>
    <a v-else href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>Favorite
    </a>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ...
        computed:{
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

It does not works

There exist error like this :

> invalid expression: v-if="Auth::user()"

How can I use auth on vue component ?

Comment: Are you building SPA or standard multi-page app ? There are no way to pass pure Laravel stuff directly into the `.vue` single file component

Comment: @Belmin Bedak, Like I do not use it

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: @M U, Great. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use Laravel variables (PHP) inside your Vue this way.
2. You should decide whether you want to build standard app or SPA.
3. If you want to build standard multipage app, you can place your VueJS components between PHP tags exactly as you do in your first example.
4. If you still want to build standard multipage app but be able to use your `Auth::user()` value, there is an option for you in point 5.
5. Pass value of `Auth::user()` to the VueJS component as prop.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Use the prop like that:

```
props: ['auth'],
(...)
<template>
    ...
    <div v-if="auth">
        <favorite :id="item.id"></favorite>
    </div>
    <a v-if="!auth" class="btn btn-block btn-success"> // avoid using v-else as per VueJS docs
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>Favorite
    </a>
    ...
</template>
```

and use your component in the code like:
`<favorite :id="{{ $store->id }}" auth="Auth::user()"></favorite>`

Not sure if you don't have to cast Auth::user() to string/int but I am pretty sure you will figure it out with php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `auth()->user()` instead of `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the auth user object to work (render without errors) as per accepted answer :(

But I could access and pass through a direct property such as id like so

```
<example :auth="Auth::user()->id"></example >
```

*Note it has to be "v-bind" because it's a dynamic property and not explicit string.*

I also got this to work as another alternative which also produces user ID.

```
auth="{{ Auth::check() }}"
```

I'd love to know how to get the object passed into the vue component?